# Поиск в многомерном массиве

Tags: массивы, javascript

Можно ли обойтись без forEach в данном примере:
Имеется массив вида

```
{ count: 0,
  models: 
 [ { name: 'ACE',
   url: 'ace',
   count: 0 },
 { name: 'Cobra',
   url: 'cobra',
   count: 0 } ],
}
```

Нужно получить значение поля "url" зная название модели "ACE" или "Cobra"

В случае с forEach решение

```
vehicle.models.forEach(function(cell, index) {
    if(cell.name === ads.car.model.name) {
        ads.car.model.url = cell.url;
    }
});
```

Может есть альтернативные варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При такой структуре альтернативы нет.

Попробуйте изменить обьект:

```
{ count: 0,
  models: {
    'ACE' : {
      url: 'ace',
      count: 0
    },
    'Cobra' : {
      url: 'cobra',
      count: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Тогда сможете проверять без цикла:

```
var _modelName = 'ACE';
if(vehicle.models.hasOwnProperty(_modelName) .....
```

Comment: эти данные их базы =( править не хотелось бы, но подумаю. спс!

Comment: Т.е. данные хранятся в JSON в текстовом поле?

Comment: да, в MongoDB

Comment: А есть возможность сохранять строку в предложенном мной варианте в момент внесения записи в БД?

Comment: база просто уже сформирована, проект еще пишется конечно.

Comment: Ну тогда вообще не вижу проблем в реализации :)